# How can a user can submit multiple Hubspot forms without needing to enter their email each time

Tags: hubspot

We have a knowledgebase portal in hubspot where we ask for different sets of information from the users via hubspot forms. With how it was set up initially, it requires the user to enter their email on every form to connect the info being submitted to their contact within hubspot.

If anyone could offer some guidance on how we can have users submit their info without having to enter their email that would be amazing.